# Angular - detectChanges does not invoke ngDoCheck()

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, zone, zonejs, change-detector-ref

I'm running cdr.detectChanges() in some nested child (Child1) that has parent and also another nested child component (Child2).

Why if I will run trigger detectChanges method in Child1 component - only ngDoCheck is invoked in Child2 component? Shouldn't it invoke DoCheck in current component (Child1) and DoCheck in Child2? How can I know that current component is also checked?

I prepared small example:
https://github.com/michalgrzegorczyk-dev/change-detection

components: (app-child1, app-child2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1053/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular) explains why that happens:

> When change detection is triggered for a particular view/component it
> does the following operations in the specified order:
>
> ...
> 6. calls OnInit and ngDoCheck on a child component (OnInit is called only during first check)

So in your case when you run `child1.detectChanges()` Angular will run `ngDoCheck` hook on the child component, which is `child2`. One of the reasons it's designed like this is to allow manual control of `OnPush` logic from the `ngDoCheck` hook. If a `child2` is defined as onPush, and no input bindings have changed, you still can call `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` from `ngDoCheck` of `child2` to mark the component as dirty. So in a way `ngDoCheck` signals that Angular is about to run check on the child component, where part of the check involves updating input props on **child** components and updating view bindings on the **current** component.